# Programmatically inviting contacts to Google Chat

Tags: api, google-contacts-api, google-talk

I'm writing a sync application for Lotus Notes and Google (I know, there are some of them out there, but they are either not free or sync only calendar (or only contacts) and most of them cannot deal with local mailfiles). This works so far, but I have a problem when syncing contacts: under certain circustances, the contacts have to be deleted and recreated in Google. This causes them to disappear from the chat list in GMail and the people have to be re-invited manually. Is there any way to send these invites through the API?

Thanks in advance

DBa

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution finally - GTalk is basically XMPP, so I took the jabber.net library and just add all gmail.com and googlemail.com addresses to the roster.